# Erro no npm do node.js |Cannot find module 'json-parse-better-errors'

Tags: javascript, node.js

Indo direto ao ponto é este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>   1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',
>   1 verbose cli   'C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>   1 verbose cli   'install',
>   1 verbose cli   'blerg' ]
>   2 info using npm@5.6.0
>   3 info using node@v8.11.2
>   4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\Acer/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
>   5 verbose stack Error: Cannot find module 'json-parse-better-errors'
>   5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>   5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>   5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>   5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>   5 verbose stack     at Object. (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:12:16)
>   5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>   5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>   5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>   5 verbose stack     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>   5 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>   5 verbose stack     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>   5 verbose stack     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>   5 verbose stack     at Object. (C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-tree\rpt.js:2:11)
>   5 verbose stack     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>   5 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>   5 verbose stack     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>   6 verbose cwd C:\Users\Acer
>   7 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
>   8 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "blergg"
>   9 verbose node v8.11.2
>   10 verbose npm  v5.6.0
>   11 error code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
>   12 error Cannot find module 'json-parse-better-errors'
>   13 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: O npm está instalado? Use `npm --version`

Comment: E voltando direto ao ponto, o que você está tentando fazer? Passe as informações relevantes a pergunta aqui, não utilize links externos.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido. Estava tudo em perfeito estado no meu ver. Aí eu testei baixar o .zip ao invés do .msi. E seu muito certo! Não sei por qual motivo se deu isto. Mas caso alguém passe pelo mesmo erro, só baixar o .zip que talvez funcione!